# Group Core Data items by category in List in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I have a Core Data container with two entities, a Category and an Item. The Item can have one Category assigned and the Category can be assigned to many Items.

What I need to do is group the items by category in a list in SwiftUI.

The code below doesn't group all items by category, it only shows one item by category. How can I group all items that have the same category assigned under the same category group?

#### Core Data Entities

```
Category
    Attributes
        name
    Relationship
        items (Type: To Many)

Item
    Attributes
        name
    Relationship
        category (Type: To One)
```

#### Swiftui

```
struct ItemsView: View {
    let selectedList:List

    @EnvironmentObject private var itemSM: ItemServiceModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(itemSM.items){ item in
                Section(header: Text(item.category?.name ?? "")) {
                    Text("\(item.name ?? "")")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
           itemSM.loadItems(forList: selectedList)
       }
    }
}
```

#### Service Item Service Model

```
class ItemServiceModel: ObservableObject{
    let manager: CoreDataManager
    @Published var items: [Item] = []

    func loadItems(forList list: List){
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
        
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.name, ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        
        let filter = NSPredicate(format: "list == %@", list)
        request.predicate = filter

        do{
            items =  try manager.context.fetch(request)
        }catch let error{
            print("Error fetching items. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I see: As you can see, `Grapes` and `Oranges` should be within the same group `Fruits & Vegetables`.

[image]

##### Edit1

Added `loadItems()` method and image.

##### Edit2

Adding an extra `ForEach` inside the `Section` I was able to group the items, my issue now is that it's adding a section for the total of items in the array.

```
List {
    ForEach(itemSM.items) { item in
        Section(header: Text(item.category?.name ?? "")) {
            ForEach(itemSM.items.filter { $0.category == item.category }) { filteredItem in
                Text("\(filteredItem.name ?? "")")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I see, as you can see, only one `Fruits & Vegetables` section should exist.

[image]

Comment: Wild guess, did you use sort descriptors when fetching the objects? I believe the sorting must match the way you want to group the objects.

Comment: Hmm, I have updated my original code to show my fetching and sorting method.

Comment: Sort by category name first, then item name

Comment: Applied a second sorting method but it made no difference.  `let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \RegularItem.category?.name, ascending: true)`
        
        `let sort2 = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \RegularItem.name, ascending: true)`
        `request.sortDescriptors = [sort, sort2]` Thanks.

Comment: I managed to reproduce this using struct instead of Core Data classes so even with the correct sorting this is also some issue with your List/Section code.

Comment: ...or you could research using a `@SectionedFetchRequest` but then you would need to move the request from the service model to the view.

Comment: Hmm, let me take a look at `SectionedFetchRequest`, although, I would rather have the code in the service model since it's how my app is structured. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. It basically returns and displays all categories and their respective items from the specified list.

#### CategoryServiceModel

```
func loadCategories(for list: List) -> ([Category], [Item]) {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Category>(entityName: "Category")

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY items IN %@", list.items ?? [])
    request.predicate = predicate

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Category.name, ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    do {
        let categories = try manager.context.fetch(request)
        var categories: [Category] = []
        var items: [Item] = []

        for category in categories {
            categories.append(category)
            if let items = category.items?.allObjects as? [Item] {
                let filteredItems = items.filter { $0.list == list }
                items.append(contentsOf: filteredItems)
            }
        }

        return (categories, items)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error fetching categories. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return ([], [])
    }
}
```

### SwiftUI

```
  List {
      ForEach(categorySM.categories) { category in
          Section(header:Text(category.name ?? "")){
              ForEach(category.items?.allObjects as? [Item] ?? []) { item in
                  Text("\(item.name ?? "")")
              }
          }
      }
  }
  .onAppear{
      categorySM.loadCategories(for: selectedList)
  }
```